# ORA-01843 error found in netbeans while injecting sql query

Tags: mysql, oracle, netbeans

Data entered from the netbeans form is not been able to insert into database table . error found is

> ORA-01843 not a valid month found occurs .

Following is the code showing error under the submit button ,

```
 private void submitnewequipActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
String status="PARK";
   String type_id=getid(typelist.getSelectedItem().toString()) ;  
   Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.print(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    System.out.print(month+1);
    System.out.print(year);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat((day)+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);

   //System.out.print(sdf.format(cal.getTime()).toString().toString());
        try {


            Statement stmt=(Statement)conn.createStatement();

            String sql="insert into eqp (id, eqp_type, name, status,make,creator,created)values('"+id.getText()+"','"+type_id+"','"+name.getText()+"','"+status+"','"+make.getText()+"','"+uname+"','"+sdf.format(cal.getTime())+"')";
             System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage() ,"Error", 2);
        }
{

    }  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building the date format as dd/MM/yyyy format as below

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat((day)+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
```

then you are passing it as a string variable in the query enclosed with `'`, so you should convert that to date format with `to_date` function

Hope you are using oracle and `created` is column with `date` datatype
try this query

```
 String sql="insert into eqp (id, eqp_type, name, status,make,creator,created)
 values('"+id.getText()+"','"+type_id+"','"+name.getText()+"','"+status+"','"+make.getText()
+"','"+uname+"',to_date('"+sdf.format(cal.getTime())+"','dd/MM/yyyy')";
```

here we specify the date passing is in dd/MM/yyyy format.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b13f/3)

Note: Always try to use parameterized queries to avoid [SQLInjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @AareebaNazeerJaliawala glad to hear. If helped mark it as answered